# Correct formatting

Tags: java, for-loop, formatting

I'm being told my formatting is off in this code, can anybody tell me what's wrong with it?

```
public class TwoDimArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 2;
        Int columns = 2;
        String[][] anArray = {{"Ireland", "Green"},{"England", "White"}};

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                System.out.println(anArray[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, can anybody tell me how to get it to print as so:

```
Ireland Green

England White

As apposed to:

Ireland

Green

England

White
```

Comment: Look into `System.out.print` vs. `System.out.println`.

Comment: Basically the formatting is OK.  However, the usual standard is to only indent 4 spaces per "nesting level", and there's a religious war over whether `{` should follow the `if`/`for` statement on the same line or be on a line of its own.  (I favor putting it on the `if`/`for` line, to make the listing more compact and easier to read.)  And there are minor stylistic issues over spaces between symbols, etc.

Comment: (Of course, some #$& just came along and "fixed" your formatting!)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the formatting. Hard-coding `rows` and `columns` is not really appropriate coding, though (i.e. if we changed the array but not those values, the program wouldn't work properly). You should go about checking lengths based on `anArray` instead.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, guys. I'm new to Java so I'm just trying to get my head around it all. I'll look into them. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot answer this, but this is helpful for me as I did not know you could have double arrays.

Answer (score 0):

the code you have written has an error :

```
Int columns = 2;
```

this would be the correct code:

```
int columns = 2;
```

and if you want that your code have this output:

**Ireland Green**

**England White**

you can use this code:

```
public class TwoDimArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[][] anArray = {{"Ireland", "Green"},{"England", "White"}};

    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < anArray.length; j++){
            System.out.print(anArray[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    }
}
```

I hope understand and help you

good lucky

Comment: Thank you for your help but I don't understand the .length bit. Also, why is there an extra System.out.println(); thrown in? Sorry, I'm pretty new to Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class TwoDimArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[][] anArray = {{"Ireland", "Green"},{"England", "White"}};   // create your array 2 dimensions

    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++){     // create for, .length is the array size, 
        for (int j = 0; j < anArray.length; j++){
            System.out.print(anArray[i][j] + " ");    // print the element of array and add one space for print with you want
        }
        System.out.println();    //when end the FOR with J variable, you has printed the row, and with println, add a one new line
    }

    }
}
```

with **.length** you get a variable size/length , in this case but your array is **array[2][2]**

and I use a **println** because when ends *println*, this method introduce a new line in the end line ,  a one line jump, and the next *println* write will be in a new line.

however the **print** , is same *print* that in C language, only write and the next *print* will be in the ends first *print*... so I enter +" " in the ends *print*

```
for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < anArray.length; j++){
        System.out.print(anArray[i][j] + " ");// First iteration of the FOR :Ireland" " second iteration of the FOR : Green" "
    }
    System.out.println(); // add a line jump for the next FOR iteration...
}
    }
```

if you still don't understand, you can try a change de " " for " , " or you can try change the println for print and you will begin to understand

I hope help you now jajaja

Good lucky